# Do new template instantiations break ABI?

Tags: c++, templates, dll, plugins, abi

### Overview

I have a `core` that dynamically loads different plugins. I explicitly instantiate templates that I export and then use them when link plugins against some version of the `core`. My expectations were, that when I add new types and template instantiations it would not break the ABI, and existing plugins would not have to be relinked.
It turned out not to be the case. When I add new instantiations I get symbols that are executed from within a different (than within the `core`) address.

### Example

The project repo can be found [here](https://github.com/ElDesalmado/template_abi_test).
Here is the code example.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7.2)

project(template_abi_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# old core
add_executable(core core.cpp)

target_compile_definitions(core
        PRIVATE BUILD_DLL
        PUBLIC DYN_LINK
        )

set_target_properties(core PROPERTIES ENABLE_EXPORTS 1)

# new core
add_executable(core_new core.cpp)

target_compile_definitions(core_new
        PRIVATE BUILD_DLL NEW_VERSION
        PUBLIC DYN_LINK
        )

set_target_properties(core_new PROPERTIES ENABLE_EXPORTS 1)

# plugin
add_library(plugin SHARED plugin.cpp)
target_link_libraries(plugin PRIVATE core)
```

core.hpp

```
#pragma once

#if defined(_WIN32)
#if defined(DYN_LINK)
#if defined(CORE_SOURCE)
#define CORE_DECL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CORE_DECL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#endif
#endif

#ifndef CORE_DECL
#define CORE_DECL
#endif

CORE_DECL int non_template();

template<typename>
struct foo_template {
    CORE_DECL static int get();
};
```

core_impl.ipp // this is a workaround for MinGW64. Otherwise it will not export symbols for in-class implemented functions.

```
#pragma once

#define CORE_SOURCE

#include "core.hpp"

template<typename T>
int foo_template<T>::get()
{
    static int val = 0;
    return ++val;
}
```

export_types.hpp - this file contains exported types for the plugin linked to an "old" version of the core

```
#pragma once

#include "core.hpp"

struct old{};

extern template struct foo_template<old>;
```

plugin.cpp

```
#include "core.hpp"
#include "export_types.hpp"

#ifdef _WIN32
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_EXPORT
#endif

extern "C"
{
DLL_EXPORT int foo_class_template();
}

int foo_class_template()
{
    return foo_template<old>::get();
}
```

core.cpp

```
#include "core_impl.ipp"
#include "core.hpp"
#include "export_types.hpp"

template struct foo_template<old>;

#ifdef NEXT_VERSION
struct new_0 {
};
template struct foo_template<new_0>;
#endif

#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // preincrement all the values
    int fooClassTemplate = foo_template<old>::get();

    auto plugin = LoadLibraryA("plugin.dll");

    auto pFooClassTemplate = reinterpret_cast<int(*)()>(GetProcAddress(plugin, "foo_class_template"));

    int pluginFooClassTemplate = pFooClassTemplate();

    std::cout << fooClassTemplate + 1 << " : " << pluginFooClassTemplate << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

So, when executing the old version (on Windows, haven't checked on Ubuntu yet) compiled with MSVC, MinGW64 or Clang, the output is as expected:

```
2 : 2
```

But when I run `core_new` that loads the same plugin, that was linked to an old version of the `core`, the result is different:

```
2 : 1
```

Indeed, if we inspect the addresses of functions called from within the `core` and `plugin`, we will see that they are different, though appear to be located within the `core.exe`

```
// code executed within main

(gdb) info sym 0x00007ff67da46be0
foo_template<old>::get() in section .text of C:\dev\builds\template_abi_test\Debug-MinGW-w64\core_new.exe

(gdb) info sym 0x00007ff67da4a0e0
foo_template<old>::get()::val in section .data of C:\dev\builds\template_abi_test\Debug-MinGW-w64\core_new.exe


// code executed within plugin's functions

(gdb) info sym 0x00007ff6c5cc6be0
foo_template<old>::get() in section .text of C:\dev\builds\template_abi_test\Debug-MinGW-w64\core.exe

(gdb) info sym 0x00007ff6c5cca0e0
foo_template<old>::get()::val in section .data of C:\dev\builds\template_abi_test\Debug-MinGW-w64\core.exe
```

To sum up here is a table:

|  | core address | plugin address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo_template::get | 0x00007ff67da46be0 | 0x00007ff6c5cc6be0 |
| foo_template::get::val | 0x00007ff67da4a0e0 | 0x00007ff6c5cca0e0 |

Since the addresses are located within the executable, I thought that the reason was symbol addresses, hence at first I was comparing symbol tables.

**Why does it happen? Can it be avoided?**

---

**This is the original text. I thought that difference in symbol addresses was the reason, but as people in the comments pointed out, symbol addresses don't matter. So it was a false direction.**

Consider the following example code for a dynamic library:

```
template <typename>
struct foo_template
{
    static inline int get()
    {
        static int val = 0;
        return ++val;
    }
};

struct foo
{
    template <typename>
    static inline int get()
    {
        static int val = 0;
        return ++val;
    }
};

template <typename>
inline int get()
{
    static int val = 0;
    return ++val;
}

struct old{};

template struct foo_template<old>;
template int foo::get<old>();
template int get<old>();

#ifdef NEXT_VERSION

struct new_0{};
template struct foo_template<new_0>;
template int foo::get<new_0>();
template int get<new_0>();

struct new_1{};
template struct foo_template<new_1>;
template int foo::get<new_1>();
template int get<new_1>();

struct new_2{};
template struct foo_template<new_2>;
template int foo::get<new_2>();
template int get<new_2>();

struct new_3{};
template struct foo_template<new_3>;
template int foo::get<new_3>();
template int get<new_3>();

#endif
```

In new versions when adding new template instantiations the ABI gets broken for class template and template member functions, while the existing code is intact.
New instantiations are added in a strict order - only after existing instantiations.

[This](https://www.diffchecker.com/WuMBDoez) is a comparison of output via `objdump -t` between "old" and "next" versions.
As it can be seen, only function template symbol `int get` hasn't changed:

```
// Old
AUX scnlen 0x1b nreloc 3 nlnno 0 checksum 0x0 assoc 0 comdat 2  
[ 90](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty  20)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000000012d0 _Z3getI3oldEiv    
[ 91](sec  2)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   3) (nx 1) 0x0000000000000070 .data$_ZZ3getI3oldEivE3val
```

```
// New
AUX scnlen 0x1b nreloc 3 nlnno 0 checksum 0x0 assoc 0 comdat 2
[ 90](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty  20)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000000012d0 _Z3getI3oldEiv
[ 91](sec  2)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   3) (nx 1) 0x0000000000000070 .data$_ZZ3getI3oldEivE3val
```

But class template and template static member functions changed their addresses:

```
// Old
    File    
[ 77](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   3) (nx 1) 0x00000000000012f0 .text$_ZN12foo_templateI3oldE3getEv   
AUX scnlen 0x1b nreloc 3 nlnno 0 checksum 0x0 assoc 0 comdat 2  
[ 79](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty  20)(scl   2) (nx 1) 0x00000000000012f0 _ZN12foo_templateI3oldE3getEv 
AUX tagndx 0 ttlsiz 0x0 lnnos 0 next 0  
[ 81](sec  2)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   3) (nx 1) 0x0000000000000080 .data$_ZZN12foo_templateI3oldE3getEvE3val 
AUX scnlen 0x4 nreloc 0 nlnno 0 checksum 0x0 assoc 0 comdat 3   
[ 83](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   3) (nx 1) 0x0000000000001310 .text$_ZN3foo3getI3oldEEiv    
AUX scnlen 0x1b nreloc 3 nlnno 0 checksum 0x0 assoc 0 comdat 2  
[ 85](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty  20)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000001310 _ZN3foo3getI3oldEEiv  
[ 86](sec  2)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   3) (nx 1) 0x0000000000000090 .data$_ZZN3foo3getI3oldEEivE3val
```

```
// New
File 
[ 77](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   3) (nx 1) 0x0000000000001370 .text$_ZN12foo_templateI3oldE3getEv
AUX scnlen 0x1b nreloc 3 nlnno 0 checksum 0x0 assoc 0 comdat 2
[ 79](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty  20)(scl   2) (nx 1) 0x0000000000001370 _ZN12foo_templateI3oldE3getEv
AUX tagndx 0 ttlsiz 0x0 lnnos 0 next 0
[ 81](sec  2)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   3) (nx 1) 0x00000000000000c0 .data$_ZZN12foo_templateI3oldE3getEvE3val
AUX scnlen 0x4 nreloc 0 nlnno 0 checksum 0x0 assoc 0 comdat 3
[ 83](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   3) (nx 1) 0x0000000000001410 .text$_ZN3foo3getI3oldEEiv
AUX scnlen 0x1b nreloc 3 nlnno 0 checksum 0x0 assoc 0 comdat 2
[ 85](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty  20)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000001410 _ZN3foo3getI3oldEEiv
[ 86](sec  2)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   3) (nx 1) 0x0000000000000110 .data$_ZZN3foo3getI3oldEEivE3val
```

Comment: Changing the location of symbols doesn't break the ABI, if it did it'd be impossible to maintain ABI compatibility

Comment: Why are you relying on symbol addresses within a shared library??

Comment: @rustyx it was an attempt to isolate the reason. I am going to modify the question.

Comment: please provide a [mre] (with a focus on minimal)

Comment: @AlanBirtles unfortunatelly, this is as minimal as I could make it to be *able to reproduce the erroneous behavior*. I could only delete the old text, but that will make your answer out of context

Comment: Its not a full example though, for example plugin.cpp is missing. As for making my answer out of context I did suggest you probably needed to ask a new question rather than editing this one...

Comment: @AlanBirtles I will add `plugin.cpp`. As for the question - I would need to rename this question, because the new one would have the exact name. Because *it is* the problem I am facing...

Comment: your plugin is linked to `core` so it uses the symbols from `core`, the symbols defined in `core_new` are separate so you have an ODR violation. Compiling your repo, deleting `core.exe`, renaming `core_new.exe` to `core.exe` so that there is only one copy, running `core.exe` now outputs your expected values. None of this is related to ABIs

Comment: @AlanBirtles thank's a lot! That was rather silly of me... That really explains the difference in addresses. If you add this to your answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symbols are linked to by name so changing the location of a symbol in a shared library doesn't change the ABI.

Your plugin is linked to `core` so it uses the symbols from `core`, the symbols defined in `core_new` are separate so you have an ODR violation. Compiling your repo, deleting `core.exe`, renaming `core_new.exe` to `core.exe` so that there is only one copy and then running `core.exe` now outputs your expected values. None of this is related to ABIs

Comment: Well, that makes sense. That means that it is not the reason in my case. I will modify my question with more suitable example.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik If you are going to completely change the question then it'd be better to ask a new question

Comment: I won't change the question, since it describes the exact problem I have. When I add new template instantiations my code breaks. I thought it is due to symbol addresses, but, apparently, it is not the reason. So I will add a minimal example that reproduces my problem